# Login Page error

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I am facing problem in the login page. When I press login button it takes me to user panel only if Remember me checkbox is checked. if it is not checked then It stays on login page. I cannot figure out error.

```
include("Database/database.php");
session_start();
if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) and isset($_COOKIE['passcode'])) {
    $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $passcode = $_COOKIE['passcode'];

    $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['pwd'] = $passcode;

    header("Location: useraccount.php");   /*Checks if cookies are set then takes me directly to useraccount.php */

    } else if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $userpwd = $_POST['userpwd'];
        $rem = $_POST['remember'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userName = '$username' AND Password = '$userpwd'";

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($row > 0) {
            $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['pwd'] = $userpwd;

            if (isset($_POST['remember']))     /*if remember me checkbox is checked than it set cookies and it takes me to useraccount.php page. But if I donot check the check box (remember me) than I am where I am on login page. */
            {
                setcookie("username", $username, time()+60*60*7);
                setcookie("passcode", $userpwd, time()+60*60*7);
            }

            header("Location: useraccount.php");     /* It should procees to              useracocunt.php page but it stays on login.php*/
        } else {
            header("Location: login.php");      /*Used this for testing purpose if login fails it takes me to homepage which is working fine*/
        }
        mysqli_close($link);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to this problem. it was all my mistake as i was redirecting header back to the login page if I haven't set the cookies.

- So if you are facing problem related to header check if you are heading it to proper location "url" for that file or
- there must be some spellings mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It helped I had same problem. I was redirecting it to the same login page after login. Didn't set my cookies conditions right

Answer (score 0):

add  if statement to cheek is saved to session.Becuase you add session but , nowhere check for it.

```
    <?php
        include("Database/database.php");
        session_start();

        if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) and isset($_COOKIE['passcode']))
        {
            $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
            $passcode = $_COOKIE['passcode'];

            $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['pwd'] = $passcode;

            header("Location: useraccount.php");   /*Checks if cookies are set then takes me directly to useraccount.php */

        }

         else if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $userpwd = $_POST['userpwd'];
            $rem = $_POST['remember'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userName = '$username' AND Password = '$userpwd'";

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($row > 0)
            {
                $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['pwd'] = $userpwd;

                if (isset($_POST['remember']))     /*if remember me checkbox is checked than it set cookies and it takes me to useraccount.php page. But if I donot check the check box (remember me) than I am where I am on login page. */
                {
                    setcookie("username", $username, time()+60*60*7);
                    setcookie("passcode", $userpwd, time()+60*60*7);
                }

                header("Location: useraccount.php");     /* It should procees to              useracocunt.php page but it stays on login.php*/
            }

            else
            {
                header("Location: login.php");      /*Used this for testing purpose if login fails it takes me to homepage which is working fine*/
            }
            mysqli_close($link);

        } if (isset($_SESSION['name']) and isset($_SESSION['pwd'])){

header("Location: useraccount.php");     /* It should procees to              useracocunt.php page but it stays on login.php*/

}

        ?>
```

Comment: hi, I have done it before and it does not helps, You see when remember is an exception if user checks it cookies are set, Still he should be logged in to his account.

Comment: I add if statement to check  the session is set , so this was missing. Please try to add this.

Comment: But make sure  in useraccount.php you  check not only for cookie , but also and session..

Comment: the problem was I was redirecting it to the login page from useraccount page

Comment: Sessions were never the problem